# How to speed up the loading time of Android 5.0(Lollipop) emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have created kitkat emulator and it is loaded fast in Eclipse ADT. But the lollipop emulator is very slow in loading. It tooks 30min(approx) to load. How to speed up this loading time.  My system configuration is,

> 4GB RAM,Windows 7,Intel i5 Processer

My created AVD configuration is,

> Screen:4.7 WXGA,
>
> RAM:512 RAM,
>
> VM HEAP: 120 ,
>
> CPU :intel.

Is there any other options to enable/do?

Comment: i will try all the possibilities which is given as answer and update you @XaverKapeller. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Is your issue solved? Please don't forget to vote and to accept the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there is not that much you can do. The Android emulator is notoriously slow and Android 5.0 has an even bigger startup time compared to earlier versions because of the now by default enabled disk encryption.

After looking through [**the documentation**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options) I found that you can use `-no-boot-anim` to remove the boot animation which decreases startup time.

You can also try [**Genymotion**](https://www.genymotion.com/) which is much faster than the emulator that comes with the SDK.

My advice is: Just test your app on a real device and only resort to the emulator if you have to.

Comment: I don't agree of testing the app on the real device from start. The last time i was creating a game with opengl es i had a buffer overflow and caused my nexus 5 to freeze for 5 minutes. I couldn't close it and i also couldn't remove the battery cause its nexus 5. Can you tell me your opinion ? you are more experienced than i am. I always test a product on phone when its stable enough and i want to check the performance.

Comment: As an aside: You can always restart your Nexus 5 even if it is frozen by holding down the power button and volume down button at the same time. Just keep them pressed until the device restarts which usually takes 5 to 10 seconds but it can sometimes take a little longer. For most apps there is no reason not to test them on a real device. If you don't mess around with the NDK than there is practically no chance to freeze or mess up your phone and even then you can always just restart it like I explained to you above.

Comment: The emulator is mainly there to test the app on different smartphones or tablets which you do not own physically. For example with Genymotion you can test your device on many different devices at the same time. You can also set sensor values or GPS position in the emulator which makes certain things easier to test than on a real device. But aside from cases like this testing on a real device will always be much faster and much more convenient.

Comment: Additionally you can maybe test the functions of your device in an emulator, but the only real way to test it is to hold a phone with the app in your hand. Because that is how people will use your app. What works great in an emulator may feel awkward or weird when you try to do the same thing by touching/swiping/whatever on a real device. Bad Usability will drive users away. Doesn't matter how great the app is on paper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [-no-boot-anim](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options) which speeds up the boot process but will not show boot animation while the emulator starts up.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by installing the Intel Atom x86 System Image in the SDK Manager.

Just open the SDK Manager and download the Intel Atom x86 System Image for Android 5.0.

[image]

You can choose between a 32-bit and 64-bit version.

After that when creating a new AVD you need to select the x86 System Image like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [intel.com](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/android-sdk-fig6.gif))</sub>

With this image my emulator takes about 3-5 seconds to start up. You can also enable Snapshots when creating or editing the AVD to additionally decrease startup time!

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on Stack Overflow. You are allowed to link to this guide, but you need to include all the essential steps of the answer here.

Comment: That's better, but not much. Imagine the link wasn't there, do you think anyone would think your answer would be helpful then? You should read [**this guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Most of the times i always describe my answer. The only reason i posted the link and didn't add anything more is because its very simple to do it. I will edit it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using Genymotion it's very good emulator and you can use it's plugins to integrate it with any development platform you are using

here is some resource's

[Genymotion website](https://www.genymotion.com)

[Plugins for android studio and eclipse](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-eclipse)